# Does creating a new certificate & CSR for an iOS app render it incompatible with the old app?

Tags: ios, phonegap-build

I want to test and publish a new PhoneGap Build version of my app, and realised the provisioning profile and the original certificate have expired.

If I create a new certificate and CSR etc, will Apple still see this as the same app when it comes to publishing, or will it treat it as a totally different app?

Thanks for your time and help.